# Integral and differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I believe this is a very basic question, but I need to know whether a function that is written as integral of continuous function is differentiable almost surely. In particular, if I have the following

$$
K(T)=\int_0^T\int_0^\infty e^{-(\beta+\delta)s}x f_{X,S}(x,s)dxds\
$$

where $f_X(x,s)$ is a continuous function and T, $\beta$ & $\delta$ are constants, is K(T) a continuously differentiable function? What are the conditions that I have to fulfill to ensure that K(T) is a continuously differentiable? 
At the moment, I was thinking that since K(T) itself is an integral, therefore it is differentiable; and that since the components within the integral is continuous, the the whole integral is continuous. Am I correct?

Comment: As the right hand side does not depend on $T$, $K$ is a constant function. I think that is not what you wanted to write, are $\beta, \delta$ $T$-dependent?